# How to draw a Shepard diagram from PCA scores?

Tags: r, data-visualization, pca

In [Legendre & Legendre 2012](https://books.google.ca/books?id=DKlUIQcHhOsC&source=gbs_book_other_versions), they are saying that it is possible to diagnostic a PCA with the Shepard diagram. What would be the procedure to draw the diagram? I don't know what to put in relation now:

```
library(vegan)
x = rnorm(10,24,1) # fake data
y = rnorm(10,12,1)
z = rnorm(10,4,1)
df=data.frame(x,y,z)
pca = rda(df,scale = FALSE)
biplot(pca, type = c("t","p"))
dist(df,method = "euc")
plot(scores(pca)$sites, asp = 1)

plot(dist(df,method = "euc"), dist(scores(pca)$sites,method = "euc"), xlab = "Distance in multidimensional space",ylab = "Distance in reduced space", main = "Shepard?")
abline(a=0,b=1)
```

[image]

[image]

> The scatter diagram of Fig. 9.1, which is often referred to as a
>   Shepard diagram (Shepard, 1962; diagrams in Shepard’s paper had their
>   axes transposed relative to Fig. 9.1), may be used to estimate the
>   representativeness of ordinations obtained using any reduced-space
>   ordination method. In principal component analysis (Section 9.1), the
>   distances among objects, in both the multidimensional space of
>   original descriptors and the reduced space, are calculated using
>   Euclidean distances (D1, eq. 7.32). The F matrix of principal
>   components (eq. 9.4 below) gives the coordinates of the objects in the
>   reduced space.
>   [image]

Comment: I've never come across a Shepard diagram before and I am not a R user, but your code seems correct to me.